# What's the best way to record payments in installments?

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, pledges, civipledge

In the setup I currently have, parents can choose to pay tuition in one annual, two bi-annual, or 10 monthly installments. I attempted to set it up as pledges, but payments do not get counted towards the pledges, nor do I seem to be able to go in afterwards and connect the payments to the pledge. (Is there any way to do this?) So as it stands, it's all manually checking whether an individual has paid for the month, there is no easy report to call up. This works at our current scale, but won't for much longer.

How would you set this up if you were to start from scratch?

Comment: What version of civicrm are you in? Are your pledges set up to use a 'self-service pledge page'? This is a special setting, I believe it's set inside each pledge separately but I may be mistaken, otherwise contributions would need to be input manually under the pledge tab to count towards the pledge.

Comment: I'm in the most recent, I believe. 4.6.10. I was unsuccessful at setting up a self-service pledges. Maybe I should attempt that again. But I wanted to be sure I wasn't missing some better way first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider using Membership Types rather than Pledges. You could set up each payment term as its own Membership Type, with different terms (ie 1-month membership that lasts for 10 months; 6-month membership; etc). Then create Membership Contribution pages for each term. You could turn on the auto-renew feature, or make that optional and setup payment reminder emails.

You could also create a new Financial Type called Registration Fee (or something similar) so that it's clearer what the payment is for. Even if you already have memberships set up for something else, you can set the system to allow multiple memberships, and just change the wording on the public-facing pages so it doesn't confuse the parents.

Caveat - I haven't set up CiviCRM this way before, but am currently considering it for one of my clients that is a preschool. I played around in the demo a bit to see if this would work as I'd like it to, and so far haven't run into anything that would make it seem otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a membership type called tuition and set the term to be 1 month at the rate for 1 month.

Then create a price set for that membership and include 3 prices and select the term which that price purchases.

For example:

price #1 is $100 and pays for 1 term (which is 1 month) and auto renew and ends after 10 months.

Price #2 is $450 and pays for 5 terms (5 months) and auto renews and ends after 10 months

So on and so forth